# TextView.setVisibility(GONE) isn't working

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, seekbar

I have a `SeekBar` with a `TextView` shown above the thumb when it's moving (as a tooltip). Also, there's an `EditText` below the seekbar:

[image: seekbar]

When I'm not moving the seekbar's thumb, the `TextView` isn't shown. It appears only when I move the thumb or change the number in the `EditText`. I want it to disappear when I stop moving the thumb, or after I finish typing in the `EditText`.

I got it to disappear on stop-tracking but problem is it sticks there if I type something in the `EditText`.

I tried:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    textView.setVisibility(GONE);
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. When I type something it appears, and it sticks there, until I move the thumb.

How can I get it to disappear after I finish typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }


                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable str) {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 500);

                }


                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                              int after) {
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            });
```

You can also add handler for post delay of 500 ms which will give more proper view.

Answer (score 1):

Try it, It looks like you are missing View.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: No... That's not the problem